# Creating reusable AngularJS Providers and Services

Tags: angularjs

When writing AngularJS providers, services, factories, etc. I would like to make them reusable across projects.

If you write something like the following, it is pretty hard to reuse it without modifying it.

```
angular.module('myApp').provider('myProvider', function () {
    return {
        $get: ['$http', function($http) {
            return {
                someFunction: function () {
                    return 'some result';
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

Now if I did something like this, I could reuse it more easily. Is this a standard practice or am I taking the wrong approach?

```
// This is defined in some other .js file maybe
function myProvider() {
    return {
        $get: ['$http', function($http) {
            return {
                someFunction: function () {
                    return 'some result';
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}

// My app.js or whatever file
angular.module('myApp').provider('myProvider', myProvider);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a reusable module like:

```
angular.module('mySharedData').provider('myProvider', function () {
    return {
        $get: ['$http', function($http) {
            return {
                someFunction: function () {
                    return 'some result';
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

To use it, make sure to load the file that defines `mySharedData`, then do:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['mySharedData'])
app.controller('myController', function ( $scope, myProvider ) {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you write something like the following, it is pretty hard to reuse it without modifying it.

Not at all. We can define module only once:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
```

and every service/provider/factory will be defined like:

```
app.provider('myProvider', function () {
    return {
        $get: ['$http', function($http) {
            return {
                someFunction: function () {
                    return 'some result';
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});

app.provider('myProvider2', function () {/*..*/}

app.service('myService', function () {/*..*/}
```

Comment: I'm missing something - if the provider is defined by referencing the app (module('myApp')), how can the provider ever be reused in another app? Must all the apps have the same name?